# Saving a data frame with a column of list in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, save

I have a data frame a below:

```
   PT       CA        DE         AP
   0         1         2        [3,4,5,6]
   1         4         6        [7,8,9]
```

when I save this data frame and read it again, the 'AP' column is stored as string:

```
   PT       CA        DE         AP
   0         1         2       '(3,4,5,6)'
   1         4         6        '(7,8,9)'
```

When I try to change it to integer by the following command, I got an error:

```
df.AP = df.apply(lambda r: [int(r.AP[j]) for j in range(len(r.AP))], axis = 1)
```

Error:

```
("invalid literal for int() with base 10: '('", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Could you please tell me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: could you pls paste your saved text file here as well ? It look like that there is a parentheses in your file.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AP column is tuple quoted in a string, so can't convert to list directly. Try this:

```
ap = r.AP.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(',')
df.AP = df.apply(lambda r: [int(ap[j]) for j in range(len(ap)], axis = 1)
```